# error angular cdk

Tags: angular

Estoy creando un proyecto en Angular con las siguientes versiones:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo un inconveniente cuando ejecuto el comando npm i angular/cdk --save, me pide ingresar a gtihub, ingrese, me sale todo correcto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero tengo me sale el siguiente error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sin esto no puedo instalar angula material, ¿Me pueden ayudar a que se debe este error?